# webservice return json data as XML in ios

Tags: objective-c, json, web-services

I'm new in ios development. I'm developing an app which  consuming soap web services and I'm facing a problem now The method in webservice return value as json string but it look like xml data which is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/“>[“data”1,”data”2,”data”3,”data”4]</string>
```

because of that I cant convert the json to NSArray using SBJSONParser when I'm trying to parse it showing the following error

**-JSONValue failed. Error is: Illegal start of token [<]**

My code is given below

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{

    if (request.responseStatusCode == 400) {
        txtCode.text = @"Invalid code";
    } else if (request.responseStatusCode == 403) {
        txtCode.text = @"Code already used";
    } else if (request.responseStatusCode == 200) {
       NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

         NSLog(@"%@",responseString);

        NSDictionary *responseArray =[responseString JSONValue];
        NSLog(@"%@",responseArray);

    } else {


       txtCode.text = @"Unexpected error";
    }


}
```

I know something wrong with my code but I cant figure out the issue please help me....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the XML to get the value of the string element, which is the JSON array. Then you send the JSON array into the JSON parser. If you want to know how to parse the XML, then here is a [good tutorial for NSXML](http://devcry.heiho.net/2012/03/parsing-xml-with-nsxmlparser.html).